# Azure service bus Topic subscription, able to have multiple sql-filter properties?

Tags: properties, filtering, metadata, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

Just a questions about Azure service bus topic subscriptions, is it possible to assign multiple properties to a single subscription?

Also is it possible to enable null values to one of the properties?

What I'm trying to do is to be able to use a azure function to somehow filter the messages on a identifier depending on if it exists or not.

I haven't been able to do this only by queue messages because i cant find a way to insert som type of metadata.

Another solution to my problem would be a separate Service bus Topic subscription where its property can accept being set and shift between to two different values, by which i then can filter.

The reason i want to do this is not to duplicate a whole sequence of actions, only to insert some kind of filtering functionality inside the action after the Service bus topic so to speak.

--------------------UPDATE-------------------

Ok So a bit of update, i've made some progress in this matter. Another question related to this matter is:

When I have sent a Brokered message to a servicebus topic subscription with a property as for example:

> message.Properties['id'] = "1";

Is it possible to access that messages propertie value some how?
I know it's probably not ment to be used this way but this would open a new door for me.

Comment: Not quite following... if you ask about having multiple rules on one subscriptions - yes you can. You can also create complex SQL filters as well.

Comment: @SeanFeldman i've made some progress in this matter and i have a followup question, please look at the update, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I checked the Service Bus client library for C# and found when creating the subscription via [NamespaceManager.CreateSubscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.namespacemanager.createsubscription?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0), we could only pass a single `Filter` or a `RuleDescription` with a single Filter as follows:

```
public SubscriptionDescription CreateSubscription(string topicPath, string name, Filter filter);
public SubscriptionDescription CreateSubscription(string topicPath, string name, RuleDescription ruleDescription);
```

As Sean Feldman mentioned about creating complex SQL filters, I created my application to test it. You could refer to my test as follows:

**Sample Message**

```
var body = "Hello World";
var message1 = new BrokeredMessage(body);
message1.Properties["From"] = "Ian Smith";
message1.Properties["MessageId"] = -1;
message1.Label = null;

var message2 = new BrokeredMessage("Second message");
message2.Properties["From"] = "Alan Smith";
message2.Label = "important";
message2.Properties["MessageId"] = 2;

var message3 = new BrokeredMessage("Third message");
message3.Properties["From"] = "Kelly Smith";
message3.Label = "information";
message3.Properties["MessageId"] = 1;
```

**Create subscription with Filter**

```
var filter=new SqlFilter("(sys.Label='important' or sys.Label IS NOT NULL) or MessageId<0 or From LIKE '%Smith'");
namespaceManager.CreateSubscription(topicName, subName,filter);
```

The above subscription could receive all the three messages. For more details, you could refer to [SQLFilter syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-sql-filter).

**UPDATE:**

For receiving messages, you could leverage [Subscription​Client.​On​Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptionclient.onmessage?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_SubscriptionClient_OnMessage_System_Action_Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_BrokeredMessage__) and refer to the following code snippet:

```html
//Processes a message in an event-driven message pump.
 client.OnMessage((receivedMessage)=>{
    Console.WriteLine(receivedMessage.Properties['id'].ToString());
    receivedMessage.Complete(); //manually mark the message as processed and deleted.  
 },new OnMessageOptions(){
   AutoComplete=false,
   MaxConcurrentCalls=5
 });
```

Comment: i've made some progress in this matter and i have a followup question, please look at the update, Thank you.

Comment: Are you mean that you want to retrieve the custom property from your client, e.g. [Subscription​Client.​On​Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptionclient.onmessage?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_SubscriptionClient_OnMessage_System_Action_Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_BrokeredMessage__) or [Queue​Client.​On​Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.onmessage?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0) ?

Comment: I'm not sure i understood you question, but lets say i send a message to the topic subscription with the property "ID" = 1, 
e.g.   message.Properties['id'] = "1";
i want to be able to retrive the value "1" from the message with that property which i sent to the topic subscription. do i make any sense? :P  @Bruce

Comment: I have updated my answer and provided the code snippet for receiving message and read the custom property, you could refer to it.

Comment: You could create your subscription via `namespaceManager.CreateSubscription(topicName, subName,new SqlFilter("id='1'"));`

Comment: Ok so this works perfectly in C# console application.. my next problem is that i'm doing this in a Azure function. which manages to read the Service bus topic message before i can fetch the message property. its a trigger, this means the message disappears from the service bus before i can fetch the property value...

Comment: AFAIK, the message could also be deserialized to `BrokeredMessage` (c#), you could modify your run.csx like this `public static void Run(BrokeredMessage mySbMsg, TraceWriter log)` and import the Microsoft.ServiceBus assembly. Here is a blog, you could refer to [it](https://blog.kloud.com.au/tag/azure-functions/). Additionally, you need to create your subscription with SQL filter first then bind it with your azure function app.

Comment: Just did that, and it worked! Thank you so much for the answer I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: Great! Any concerns, feel free to let us know.

Comment: @BruceChen Can i apply sql filter on any of the message body properties? I was able to do that with RabbitMQ but not sure about azure topic.

Comment: AFAIK, the filter expression could only apply on the public property of the BrokeredMessage class or the key of the BrokeredMessage class dictionary (e.g. BrokeredMessage.Properties).